# Browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

When we call the html page in browser with images in Mozilla Firefox browser could not load image in windows but in chrome images are showing even in IE also , And when we call same page in Ubuntu Mozilla Firefox the image will be display, same issue in Mac in Mozilla  Firefox image could not load display. But in safari browser images are display.

And when we run Mozilla Firefox in safe mode that fine and display images in windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions:

1. Clear cookies and cache
2. Images may not be loaded due to security issues and so you can try:                Click the Site Identity Button->More information… button->Permissions panel->Select Allow( next to Load Images)->Refresh and try again

source:

> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show